# deep copy of GeoDataFrame becomes Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, deep-copy

When I [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` without a "geometry" column, the copy becomes a `pandas.DataFrame`. Why does this happen? I looked on the main branches on Github and neither Pandas nor Geopandas override `__deepcopy__`.

```
import copy
import geopandas as gpd

empty = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
print("original plain:", type(empty))
print("copied plain:", type(copy.deepcopy(empty)))

geom = gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns=["geometry"])
print("original with geometry:", type(geom))
print("copied with geometry:", type(copy.deepcopy(geom)))
```

Output:

```
original plain: <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
copied plain: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
original with geometry: <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
copied with geometry: <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>
```

Comment: We're discussing this on Github: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/2765 . Basically, __deepcopy__ is actually defined, and it calls the constructor again, and the constructor does something special with an empty GeoDataFrame.

Comment: This should be fixed in Pandas v0.13.0: https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2775